# Why python post request with nordvpn socks proxy doesn't work on distant hosted server while working on local windows?

Tags: python, proxy, socks, proxies

On a python app, i send a request post through a socks proxy of nordvpn :
(los-angeles.us.socks.nordhold.net)

```
prox = {'https':'socks5://user:pass@host:port'}
requests.post(url, proxies=prox, data=data)
```

While this code works on my local windows environnement, the request been sent and received, the code gets an error when the app is hosted on a shared server.

```
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy los-angeles.us.socks.nordhold.net:1080:
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Hoster says i need a root ssh access from a dedidated server. But how would it help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
amsterdam.nl.socks.nordhold.net
atlanta.us.socks.nordhold.net
dallas.us.socks.nordhold.net
dublin.ie.socks.nordhold.net
ie.socks.nordhold.net
los-angeles.us.socks.nordhold.net
nl.socks.nordhold.net
se.socks.nordhold.net
stockholm.se.socks.nordhold.net
us.socks.nordhold.net
```

Port is 1080
your username is manually setup credentials and passwords too.
Dont try to use ur login data for it because it will never work.
Try with closing the connection.